# compare only date and month for conditional column update in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have this code in a stored procedure:

```
d01072016 = case when '07-01-2016' between pp.committedstart and  pp.committedend then 'y' 
                 when '07-01-2016' < pp.committedstart then 's' 
                 when '07-01-2016' > pp.committedend then 'g' end
```

based on the date it updates a particular column.

Now I want to compare only date and month so that it becomes *year independent*.

The date format in SQL Server is `mm-dd-yyyy` and the table column name is like `dd-mm-yyyy` but I can always this table column name to match to `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Please help.

Comment: What does it mean: *but I can always this table column name to match to*? Please, re-phrase.

Comment: Join the date you are testing to a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). Use the day and month fields of the calendar to see if it matches the numbers you are interested in.

Comment: hi gofr1, it is just that the column name is not in the same format as in sql server date -- column name = mmddyyyy; whereas the date is saved in the table as mm-dd-yyyy. Any way this is a confusing info I had made... sorry